# How to implement custom`snapshotState` in KafkaSource & KafkaSourceReader

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We are migrating to [KafkaSource](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-connectors/flink-connector-kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/connector/kafka/source/KafkaSource.java) from [FlinkKafkaConsumer](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-connectors/flink-connector-kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/FlinkKafkaConsumer.java).
We have disabled auto commit of offset and instead  committing them manually to some external store

We override [FlinkKafkaConsumer](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-connectors/flink-connector-kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/FlinkKafkaConsumer.java) and then on an overridden instance of [KafkaFetcher](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-connectors/flink-connector-kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/internals/KafkaFetcher.java)  we try to store the **offset** in some external store by overriding `doCommitInternalOffsetsToKafka`

```
 protected void doCommitInternalOffsetsToKafka(Map<KafkaTopicPartition, Long> offsets,
        @Nonnull KafkaCommitCallback commitCallback) throws Exception {
//Store offset in S3
}
```

Now In order to migrate we tried coping/overriding `KafkaSource`, `KafkaSourceBuilder` and `KafkaSourceReader`, but looks like a lot of redundant code which somehow does not look correct to me.

In Custom KafkaSourceReader I tried overriding `snapshotState`

```
@Override
public List<KafkaPartitionSplit> snapshotState(long checkpointId) {
   // custom logic to store offset in s3
   return super.snapshotState(checkpointId);
}
```

Is this correct or Is there any other way to achieve the same.

Comment: Why not simply use S3 as state backend so the checkpoint state will be saved onto S3?

Comment: Since we are migrating to flink 1.14, we don't want to change a lot. There is/was an existing logic of storing kafka offset in some external store, so want to acheive the same

Comment: Apart from writing your own Kafka source, I don't see a better way than what you are doing right now.